# Regression equation formatting

Tags: regression, categorical-data, regression-coefficients

I have a simple question for you, which has to do with style. Since I am a novice in writing research papers, I have the small issue of not knowing how to represent an equation in an acceptable way.

I am running an OLS regression, for which I use year fixed effects. Since I do not wish to write up every b*year-dummy combination, what is the appropriate way to write this in a paper?

I am thinking of writing it as:

yi = β0 +β1xi+ ... + SUM(b*year-dummy) + e

Is there a standard way to write this, or is it common to just say the regression included time fixed effects in writing?

Comment: Accepted style tends to be affected by which area you're working in - and sometimes, by what a particular journal expects.